# Calculate difference between current date and a date and start counting time from the difference value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a grid with data. I execute the load grid () function to load data or conditions before the grid is loaded completely.

When the atctive state is equal to 1 I intend that in this line a timer is started through the difference of the current date with the date of the object (date.key.date).

That is, if the difference is 30 minutes ... I want the timer to start counting from 00:30:00 ...

My problem is that the timer is not being started and I cannot pass the value of it to the function of the fetchdisplay () service;

Can someone help me?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5dwvg3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**code**

```
data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      idUser: 1,
      name: "Name1",
      active: 1,
      date: "2020-02-01T20:00:00",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      idUser: 2,
      name: "Name2",
      active: 0,
      date: "2020-02-01T20:00:00",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      idUser: 3,
      name: "Name3",
      active: 0,
      date: "2020-02-01T20:00:00",
    }
  ];


  loadgrid(event) {
    if (event != null) {
      if (event.rowType != "header") {
        if (event.data.decorrer == 1){
          this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.display = +this.datePipe.transform(Date.now(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'); - +this.datePipe.transform(event.data.date, 'yyyyMMddHHmmss');
            // this.taskService.fetchDisplay() = this.display;
            return this.display;

          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  startTimer(data) {
    alert("start timer");
    this.currentRowIndex = data.id;
    let self = this;
    self.taskService.startTimer(data);
    self.currentState = self.taskService.getCurrentState();
  }

  pauseTimer(data) {
    alert("pause timer");
    let self = this;
    this.currentRowIndex = data.id;
    self.taskService.pauseTimer(data);
    self.currentState = self.taskService.getCurrentState();
  }
```

Comment: Your code looks incomplete, what are `this`, `self`, `event` pointing to?

Comment: @Addis You were right, I had an error in the code, you can check now

Answer (score 1):

There are some missing information from your question but you would generally do that with `setInterval` by updating the count every second which will get the difference between the current date and the given date. In your case the given date could be like `Date.parse(data[0].date)`:

```js
data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      idUser: 1,
      name: "Name1",
      active: 1,
      date: "2020-02-01T20:00:00",
    }
    ]
    
const date = Date.parse(data[0].date);  //the date of the object
const elem = document.getElementById('counter')

function count() {

  let countFrom = (Date.now() - date); //get the difference with the current date
  
  //convert to seconds, minutes and hours
  seconds = parseInt((countFrom/1000) % 60)
  minutes = parseInt((countFrom/(1000*60)) % 60)
  hours = parseInt((countFrom/(1000*60*60)) % 24);

  //append `0` infront if a single digit
  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
 
  let time = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  elem.textContent = time;
  
}

setInterval(count, 1000);
```

```html
<div id='counter'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but is it possible to pass the value to the this.taskService.fetchDisplay () function?

Comment: You were right, I had an error in the code, you can check now

Comment: which value? and what does this function do?

Comment: my difficulty now is to present this value in the format hh: mm: ss and not in the format yyyyMMddHHmmss

Comment: normally the way you pass a value to a function is `this.taskService.fetchDisplay(value);` But since I don't know how the function is implemented, that could not be the actual case.